# using service principal password created in config later on in same config

Tags: azure, terraform

I have the following code:

```
resource "random_string" "password" {
  length               = 16
  special              = true
  override_special     = "_%@"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "auth" {
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.auth.id
  value                = random_string.password.result
  end_date_relative    = "240h"
}
```

I want to use the password in a resource to create an AKS cluster:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "default" {
  name                = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-aks"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.default.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.default.name
  dns_prefix          = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-k8s"

  default_node_pool {
    name            = var.node_pool
    node_count      = var.node_count
    vm_size         = var.vm_size
    os_disk_size_gb = 30
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = azuread_service_principal.auth.application_id
    client_secret = azuread_service_principal_password.auth.value
  }

  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "Demo"
  }
}
```

However, when I run terraform apply, I get:

```
Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│ 
│   with azuread_service_principal_password.auth,
│   on aks-cluster.tf line 26, in resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "auth":
│   26:   value                = random_string.password.result
│ 
│ Can't configure a value for "value": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this
│ configuration.
```

Is there a way of generating the service principal password in my config and then using it later on in the same configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of generating the service principal password in my
> config and then using it later on in the same configuration?

If your question is to set a user defined password/secret for a Service Principal, then it is not possible to do so.

`azuread_service_principal_password` is essentially a wrapper over [`servicePrincipal: addPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Graph API call which does not allow you to specify your own password/secret.

Comment: I'm not bothered about setting this, I just want a password that I can use later on in the config, is this still not possible ?

Comment: If you remove `value                = random_string.password.result` from your code, you should be able to use the password generated later on (`client_secret = azuread_service_principal_password.auth.value`). I believe the error is coming at the line where you are trying to set the value of the password. Can you give that a try?

Comment: However please note that the password/secret is only returned once immediately after creation. After that it is not possible to retrieve the password/secret.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `azuread_application_password` instead of `azuread_service_principal_password` so you can specify the random string value.